# How to convert entity to string?

Tags: entity

I have an entity `city`. For example, I run `{city} = GeoNearest["City", GeoPosition[{41.8, -87.7}]]` and then I got The entity "Chicago" as my output of `city`.

I want to have the string "Chicago" instead entity "Chicago" as output.

How can I convert `city` from entity to string?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `Entity` should have a `"Name"` property that returns a string,

[image]

If you have `city` defined as an entity, these three give the same result

```
city @ "Name"
EntityValue[city, "Name"]
EntityProperty["City", "Name"] @ city
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that `GeoNearest` returns a list, if you want to define your variable in one line, you can use this: `city=First[GeoNearest["City", GeoPosition[{41.8, -87.7}]]]["Name"]`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the functions `CanonicalName`, which gives the `InputForm` of the city's name, and `CommonName`, which gives the following.
[image: an example of the application of CanonicalName and CommonName on a sample geographic entity]